# Пунктуационное оформление диалога

Tags: пунктуация

Как известно, чаще всего повествовательное предложение в диалоге оформляется так:
*-Текст, - слова автора.*
Но есть случаи, когда после текста ставится точка и, соответственно, слова автора начинаются с большой буквы. Вот, например:
*-Специалисты не могут объяснить, почему совы решили изменить свой распорядок дня. — Тут диктор позволил себе ухмыльнуться. — Очень загадочно.*
Хотелось бы знать, в каких ситуациях уместно поставит точку после слов героя и чем это отличается от диалога с запятой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Розенталя есть правило:

Если авторские слова, стоящие после прямой речи, представляют собой отдельное предложение, то они начинаются с прописной буквы:
— Скорей, загорелась школа! — И он побежал по домам будить людей.
http://modernlib.ru/books/rozental_ditmar_elyashevich/spravochnik_po_russkomu_yaziku_punktuaciya/read_17/

Считается, что в этом случае авторская вставка описывает действие, не характеризующее непосредственно предшествующее законченное высказывание персонажа. А в приведенном тексе из "Гарри Поттера"  это именно авторская вставная конструкция.